# Probability of m crossings of 0 before time 1 of a standard Brownian motion

Tags: pr.probability, random-walks, brownian-motion

Let $B$ be a standard Brownian motion. Could anyone show some hints and reference about how to compute the following probability?

Let $N(n) = \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{1}_{\{0 \in B[\frac{i-1}{n},\frac{i}{n}] \}}$, Then for any $m <n$, what is 
$$
\mathbb{P}\left( N(n) < m \right)?
$$

I have already known that $\mathbb{P}(\exists t\in (a,b): B(t)=0) = \frac{2}{\pi}\arctan\sqrt{\frac{b-a}{a}}$, so $\mathbb{E}\left( N(n) \right) \approx \sqrt{n}$. What I really want to proof is that for any $\epsilon > 0$, $\mathbb{P}\left( N(n) < n^{\frac{1}{2}(1-\epsilon)} \right)$ is summable.

Comment: Isn't that essentially the same as the probability that $M_1\le n^{-1/2-\epsilon}$ where $M_t=\max_{0\le s<t}X_t$? If so, the distribution of $M_1$ can be found under running maximum at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process>.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas Hi, Anthony, I think there is a notation problem in $N(n)$, so we are talking about different things. I have fixed it. Sorry for this notation. I want to talk about the crossings around $x$-axis.

Comment: With probability one, the dimension (both Hausdorff and box-counting) of the zero set is $\tfrac{1}{2}$, so with probability one we have $\log N(n,\omega) \sim \log n^{1/2}$. By Fubini's theorem, this implies summability of $\mathbb{P}(N(n,\omega) < n^{(1 - \epsilon) / 2})$. In fact, if I remember correctly, the $\tfrac{1}{2}$-dimensional box-counting measure of the zero set is equal to the local time, so we have $N(n, \omega) \sim L(\omega) n^{1/2}$, where $L(\omega)$ is the local time of $B(t)$ at zero.

Comment: I was wrong with the last statement: a correct one seems to be something like $N(n,\omega) \sim L(\omega) \psi^{-1}(1/n)$, where $\psi(h) = h^{-1/2} (\log \log h^{-1})^{1/2}$, at least for the Hausdorff dimension variant; see Theorem 1.2 in [Baraka–Mountford, *The Exact Hausdorff Measure of the Zero Set of Fractional Brownian Motion*, J. Theor. Probab (2011) 24: 271–293](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/159151848.pdf).

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki Hi, Mateusz, thank you for your comment. Could you please explain a little more where you apply the Fubini's theorem? Moreover, It is clear that $N(n, \omega) > L(\omega) n^{1/2(1-\epsilon)}$ a.s., but to get my conclusion, we don't know that $L(\omega)$ is uniformly bounded in [0,1] independent of $\omega$. In fact it may be achieved by compute the probability of the local time no larger than $n^{1/2 \epsilon}$.

Comment: @WenboLi: You are right, summability of $\mathbb{P}(N(n) < n^{1/2(1-\epsilon)})$ requires some uniformity with respect to $\omega$. Sorry for that error, I will try to find a workaround.